# I am learning react and my code is working fine but how can i declare currDate single time to use it globally to use in useState

Tags: reactjs, mern, reactjs-flux, react-fullstack, reactjs-testutils

How can I declare currDate globally to use it in useState. The following code works just fine but wish to make it more efficient.

Is there any better way to shorten the code?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
        
const Clock = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  const currDate = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  const [currTime, updateTime] = useState(currDate);
  console.log(currDate);

   
  const timeHandler = () => {
    console.log(1);
    const date = new Date();
    const currDate = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    updateTime(currDate);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1> {currTime}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={timeHandler}>
        Updatetime
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to make it short, rather than repeating the lines that gets `currDate` from `toLocaleTimeString`. You create a function that does that, and use it wherever you want.

### EXAMPLE - 1

```
function getCurrDate() {
  return (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()
}

const Clock = () => {
  const [currTime, updateTime] = useState(getCurrDate());

  return (
    <>
      <h1> {currTime}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => updateTime(getCurrDate())}>
        Updatetime
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

### EXAMPLE - 2

Store the recent date on the state and derive `toLocaleTimeString()` from it.

```
const Clock = () => {
  const [currTime, updateTime] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <>
      <h1> {currTime.toLocaleTimeString()}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => updateTime(new Date())}>
        Updatetime
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
  1 import React, { useState } from 'react';
  2 
  3 const getTime = () => {
  4   const date = new Date();
  5   const currDate = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  6 
  7   return currDate;
  8 };
  9 
 10 function Clock() {
 11   const [currTime, updateTime] = useState(getTime());
 12 
 13   const timeHandler = () => {
 14     updateTime(getTime());
 15   };
 16 
 17   return (
 18     <>
 19       <h1> {currTime}</h1>
 20       <button type="button" onClick={timeHandler}>
 21         Updatetime
 22       </button>
 23     </>
 24   );
 25 }
 26 
 27 export default Clock;
```